# create ios apps in ubuntu

Tags: development, ios

I need to develop an app for iphones. I have a laptop that runs on ubuntu. Can we develop the complete code, run and test it on ubuntu machine?

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/243310/can-i-develop-ios-games-on-ubuntu but this might be better: http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2014/02/11/building-a-phonegap-ios-app-from-ubuntu-entirely-without-mac-os-x/